# Java - How to check PC sleep mode (Quartz Scheduler + Selenium)

Tags: java, selenium, quartz-scheduler

Currently I am using Quartz Scheduler to schedule an automated (Selenium-based) job at certain time (lets say 3PM) everyday. The job is to automate a health declaration form on a website using ChromeDriver.

The problem is that the PC will crashed (BSOD). It occurs if the PC is sleep when it's 3pm, later (let say 3:20pm) the user will wake the PC up, freeze + crash occur.

I have tried multiple ways but there seems to be no clear tutorial on how to check if PC is in Sleep mode or not. I know many people suggest JNA but I can’t seem to get a good understanding of how to set it up.

Is there any workaround this issue?

Edit:
I have tried experimenting in the Job class, and it seems the crash issue will occur even without Selenium. Hence, I might need to find workaround with the Quartz Scheduler somehow?

Comment: Have you tried contacting Quartz Scheduler tech support? This is clearly not your problem. When Windows is in sleep mode, basically all apps are suspended. If this causes your machine to crash, they must be doing something they're not supposed to. What you SHOULD NOT do, is looking for ways to circumvent those safeguards. Alternatively, you can disable sleep mode on that computer.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I develop an automated program using selenium that will run at specific time every day(without the need for user to use Windows Task Scheduler or whatsoever). So I used Quartz Scheduler for schedule. I tried to research about JNA but not so much info / tutorial that I got

Comment: Any specific reason to use Quartz Scheduler to schedule an automated test? Why you are not using Jenkins (https://www.jenkins.io/) to do the same.